# deriving the integral of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ using an integrating factor

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find a way of deriving the function $g(x)$ that is required to find the integral below (if it exists):
$$\int\frac{1}{f(x)}dx=\int\frac{g(x)}{f(x)g(x)}dx$$
of course for this to be useful we require $g(x)$ to satisfy the DE:
$$g(x)=f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)$$
which can be rearranged to:
$$\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=-\frac{f'(x)-1}{f(x)}$$
however in the cases of $\sec,\text{sech}$ etc. the same problem arises since we have the integal from the start. If the DE is satisfied then the integral is equal to $\ln|f(x)g(x)|$.
I have noticed that using this formulae for $f(x)=\cos(x)$ we get:
$$\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=\tan(x)+\sec(x)$$
which is what we want our value of g to b. Have i missed something here?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to integrate $\int \sec(x)\,dx$?

Comment: I'm asking if anyone knows a better way of finding why we multiply by tan(x)+sec(x) when integrating sec(x)

Comment: @HenryLee why not just ask that then?